# How to avoid N+1 when using lazy loading

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I've never used the lazy loading (using virtual keyword) because, once I tried, I found there is N+1 problem if I use lazy-loading.

For example,

```
 public class Blog 
{  
    public int BlogId { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Url { get; set; }  
    public string Tags { get; set; }  
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }  
}

db.Blog.Select(x=> new {
    name = x.Name,
    postCnt = x.Posts.Count()
}).ToList();
```

**That will not join the tables, the queries will be run as many as the number of posts.**

So I do, remove the 'virtual' keyword for eager-loading. and do

```
db.Blog.include("Posts").Select(x=> new {
    name = x.Name,
    postCnt = x.Posts.Count()
}).ToList();
```

**All my controller returns a Json data**, so I've never use the lazy-loading.

But, when I see many tutorial or blogs, it seems, everyone are using the virtual keyword? that make me feel that I'm missing something, and I feel I'm doing something wrong way.

Could you please advise me what I am not understanding and what I am doing wrong?

And,

> in eager loading we load all the objects in memory as soon as the
>   object is created.

I see that in some tutorial, but I think, the object will not load any related data unless using 'include'.

Am I right? or it load all related object anyway?

[Edited, adding some more example codes]

```
public class Post {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BlogId {get; set;}
    public string title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BlogId")]         
    public virtual Blog blog { get; set; }
}


db.Post.Select(x => new {
    id = x.id,
    blogName = x.Blog.name
}).ToLost();
```

Comment: What's the definition of `Post`? It could be a navigation problem.

Comment: @PeterSmith I added the Post example code, could you take a look please?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid N+1 with lazy loading, since only .Include() saves you from it. Lazy Loading is nice in some scenarios, but for web services that return DTOs it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a point I do not understand in your case

considering:

```
from fd in Folders
select new {
    id = fd.IdFolder,
    c = fd.Files.Count()
}
```

with:

```
Folder {
    /*...*/
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[idDossier] AS [idDossier], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[tableF] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[idDossier] = [Extent2].[idDossier]) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[tableD] AS [Extent1]
```

with (or in fact without the virtual):

```
Folder {
    /*...*/
    public ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

I got the exact same query even with:

```
Folders.Include("Files").
Select( fd => new {
    id = fd.IdFolder,
    c = fd.Files.Count()
})
```

If you want a join to get sql like:

```
select
    fd.IdDossier,
    count(fl.idDossier)
from
    tableD fd
    left join tablef fl on fd.IdDossier = fl.idDossier
group by fd.idDossier
```

I just don't know how to do as

```
from fd in Folders
join fl in Files on fd.IdFolder equals fl.IdFolder into g
select new {
    id = fd.IdFolder,
    c = g.Count()
}
```

leads to the same N+1 SQL

Comment: Thank you for your commenting, How about in this case, Files.Select( x => new { fileName = x.name, folderName = x.Folder.name }); ?